# After publishing project from Visual Studio 2022, there is no views published in folder, also no bin folder, all dlls are published in the root

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have just published a test MVC web project from visual studio in my local folder.

After publishing project from Visual Studio 2022, there is no views published in folder, also no bin folder, all dlls are published in the root folder.

Please look at the attached screenshot.

why this changes?

[please see the screenshot after published] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv8OY.png)

I expected to see all views in published folder, like we used to see in earlier version of visual studio.